# Open Composite Newton–Cotes formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I'm after an Open Composite Newton-Cotes formula.

The reason for this is I have a function that I know at N evenly spaced interior grid points but I do not know it at the two endpoints.

I'm after something that is of reasonably high order, At least as good as [Simpson's 3/8 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Simpson.27s_3.2F8_rule_.28for_n_intervals.29)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You have told us about a problem, but did not ask an actual question. Could you specify what you would like to know?

Comment: You can find the parameter of the rules on Wikipedia. What exactly is question?

Comment: I guess I don't know how to express the question differently. The formula on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas#Open_Newton.E2.80.93Cotes_formulae) are not the composite rules. I'm looking for the composite formula of say degree 4, that doesn't include the end point (because in my application they are unknown). So I guess the question is can you give me a composite newton-cotes formula that doesn't include the end points?

Comment: Composite rules work always in the same way. Transform $f$ on a subinterval $[x, x+h]$ to a function on $[0,1]$, say $g(t) = f(x + th) h$, apply the rule you like on $g$, and sum up the rules on every subintervals.

Comment: But how does it work in the situation where you want to use an open formula? Do you end up not using internal points?

Comment: What I mean is do you end up not using all internal points?

Comment: probably it is easier to use an open $3$ points rule at the begin and at the end and just apply whatever composited rule you like for the other in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ and $x_i = a + ih$, $f_i = f(x_i)$, for $i= 1, \dotsc, N$ and $h = (b-a) / (N+1)$.
We want to approximate $\int_a^b f$ using a quadrature rule of at least order $4$. Thus, we apply Milne's rule for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_{N-2},x_{N-1}, x_N$, and Simpson's rule for $x_4,\dotsc, x_{N-3}$.

Assume $N = 3M$.
We obtain:

\begin{align}
\int_a^{x_4} f & \approx \frac{4h}{3} (2f_1 - f_2 + 2f_3), \\
\int_{x_{3i+1}}^{x_{3i+3}} f & \approx \frac{2h}{6} (f_{3i+1} + 4f_{3i+2} + f_{3i+3}), \quad i=1,\dotsc, M-2, \\
\int_{x_{N-3}}^b f & \approx \frac{4h}{3} (2f_{N-2} - f_{N-1} + 2f_{N}).
\end{align}